# How to remove one element from another with JSoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

For example, in this element:

```
<b><a id="Dr_Michael_Moriarty">Michael Moriarty</a> and Moriartybitcoin</b>
```

How can one remove

```
<a id="Dr_Michael_Moriarty">Michael Moriarty</a>
```

from the original element to obtain "and Moriartybitcoin" as String?
Apparently "element.empty()" does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can `remove()` elements from DOM.

Demo:

```
String text = "<b><a id=\"Dr_Michael_Moriarty\">Michael Moriarty</a> and Moriartybitcoin</b>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(text);

Elements bElement = doc.select("b");

System.out.println(bElement);
bElement.select("a").remove();

System.out.println(bElement);
System.out.println(bElement.text());
```

Output:

```
<b><a id="Dr_Michael_Moriarty">Michael Moriarty</a> and Moriartybitcoin</b>
<b> and Moriartybitcoin</b>
and Moriartybitcoin
```

You see here original `b` element, then with removed `a`, and text represented by such element after removal.